# Insert custom text on datagridview row export to TXT

Tags: vb.net, export-to-text

For the code below, I want to put at the beginning of each line exported in TXT the following text : "S,1,___***,*,**;" + the row exported from database.

How can I add for each line that text on export? For the moment I have the text only on the firs line ( check pictures attached)

```
  If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Lista este goala")
    Else
        If Directory.Exists("C:\test") = False Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\test")
        End If
        Dim sFile As String = "C:\test\test.txt"
        If File.Exists(sFile) = True Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(sFile,  

            FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
            FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        End If

        Using f As New IO.StreamWriter(sFile, True)




            Dim col As String = ""
            Dim a As String = "S,1,______,_,__;"
            Dim row As String = ""
            Dim i As Integer = 0

            For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                    row = row & Convert.ToString(r.Cells(c.HeaderText).Value) & ";"
                Next
                If i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then row &= Environment.NewLine



            Next
            f.WriteLine(a & row)


        End Using


        Using f2 As New IO.StreamWriter(sFile, True)

            Dim col As String = ""

            Dim row As String = ""
            Dim i As Integer = 0

            For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows
                For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView3.Columns
                    row = row & Convert.ToString(r.Cells(c.HeaderText).Value) & ";"
                Next
                If i < DataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1 Then Row &= Environment.NewLine
            Next


            f2.WriteLine("T,1,______,_,__;" & row)
            f2.Close()



            MessageBox.Show("Bon printat")
        End Using
    End If
```

And also a picture with exported file:

- the red circled line is the way that I need for export
- the red circle string from code is my input which is mandatory for each line followed by DGV lines export.

[Actual TXT export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzI5h.png)
[Actual Code for input my mandatory text before DGV export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8Wb.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provide some debug detail like what is `Rows.Count` etc.

If it is not going inside loop and even there are rows, better you try with accessing object in DataSource.
Something like ForEach loop on `((DataTable)DataGridView1.DataSource).Rows`

Comment: The code that I used is copied from another source. The only thing is that I want to write on each loop also the "a" string Dim a As String = "S,1,______,_,__;" together with row string row = row & Convert.ToString(r.Cells(c.HeaderText).Value) & ";"